# Replicating Squarespace's simple like buttons

Tags: jquery, facebook, wordpress, social-media, squarespace

How can I reproduce the floating hearts upon clicking the "like" button that Squarespace provides? I'm trying to implement this on a Wordpress site (not a Squarespace site).

This functionality can be seen on this site: http://ishimoto-demo.squarespace.com/blog/